# Auto Click a Button after specific time Chrome console

Tags: javascript

I want to add some code to chrome console to make sure the button is clicked automatically in a web page after 3 seconds.
The code of the button element is:

```
  input type="submit" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:submitImageButton" value="SUBMIT" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_submitImageButton" accesskey="M" class="button-large-primary" alternatetext="Submit (Alt + M)"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<input type="submit" ....>` instead of `<code>input type="submit" name=...</code>`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should attempt to solve the problem yourself and include a [mcve]. Also, it's not clear what you are trying to do... "add some code to Chrome console" makes it sound like you just want some JavaScript that you can paste into the console, but then "make sure the button is clicked automatically after 3 seconds" sounds like you want something more than that... because pasting into the console would not be automatic. Take a look at [ask] and update your question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use setTimeout

```js
setTimeout(() => {
 document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click();
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, 
It shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:2:65

Comment: Did you try changing the selector? I've updated my answer.

Comment: But how to make the code works repeatedly?

Comment: You should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` then if you want it to trigger every 3 seconds but it won't work if the page reloads as you are triggering a submit button.

Comment: You are right. It is not work because the page reloads. Could you recommend me some keywords to solve this?

Comment: Why are you using the console for this? If it's for automation you should be using some library such as [https://nightwatchjs.org/](https://nightwatchjs.org/) for automating events.

Comment: And also please do try to solve the problem by yourself and post where you are getting stuck at before posting a question. Also please do approve the answer if it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing after clicking a button it will trigger a function like after 3 seconds disable the button you can do just by setting the time out and trigger the function which will disable the button
like this

lets suppose button had id btn

```
   let button = document.getElementById('btn');

    const cb = () =>{
             console.log(button);
}

               setTimeout(cb,3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will click automatically the submit button after 3 sec. You can change your expected time like reduce or extend from here `3e3`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_submitImageButton').trigger('click');
}, 3e3);
```